# Protected Route in React, not passing parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a protected route as shown in the code below:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component:Component, authenticated, ...rest}) =>{
    console.log(authenticated);
   return(
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            authenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} {...rest} />
            : <Redirect to="/Login"/>
        )} />);

    }
export default PrivateRoute;
```

I am passing the following params in my Router configuration:

```
<PrivateRoute component={Appointments} authenticated={this.state.authenticated} exact path="/appointments" render={(props) => <Appointments {...props} appointments={this.state.appointments} />} />
```

.

However, when I try routing, it appears that the "appointments={this.state.appointments}" prop is not getting passed to the "Appointments" component.

This is the error that I get

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are passing props in the render property of the `PrivateRoute` which is as `render={(props) => <Appointments {...props} appointments={this.state.appointments} />}`. Now this property is not being Utilised in your actual component rendering in the `PrivateRoute`. Try following during your initialisation of route:

```
<PrivateRoute component={Appointments} authenticated={this.state.authenticated} exact path="/appointments"  appointments={this.state.appointments} />
```

This should fix your issue. I would suggest here that rather than creating a PrivateRoute of your own, you can use a React [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to create an authentication wrapper on the actual component.

Comment: Thanks Pranay. I'll give this a shot in a while and respond. Appreciate the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {

```
 const isAuthenticated = (location) => {
    //if loading show loading indicator
 }

const childrenWithLocation = (location) => Children.map(children, child => {
    if (isValidElement(child)) {
        return cloneElement(child, { to: child.props?.to + location.search });
    }
    return child;
});

return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
            isAuthenticated(location)
                ? (childrenWithLocation(location))
                : (<Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/login" + location.search,
                        state: { from: location }
                    }}
                />)
        }
    />
);
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work with react 17. Results in `TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '{ to: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'.       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'to' does not exist in type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'.`